# Custom jCarousel Trigger - End of Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel, jcarousellite

I am using jCarousel to show a list of items.  Lets say there are 8 items.  I am showing 4, waiting 10 seconds, then scrolling to show the last 4.  I'd like it to then show the first four and then throw a trigger that tells it to rebind data. The items would update and continue cycling like this.

These items are being loaded through jquery.load [ajax].  I want the items to rebind after they all show.  It'd be even better if I could get them to rebind after cycling twice.  I was rebinding the data using setInterval (time based), but I'd like it to be dynamic so I don't have to change the javascript timer later down the road when more items are added.

My calling code looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        updateConsoles();


        $("#tableapp").ajaxStop(function () {                
            scrollwindow();
        });
    });      

    function updateConsoles() {
        $('#tableapp').load('AjaxPages/ApplicationMonitor.aspx #application');
    }        
    function scrollwindow() {
        $("#tableapp").jCarouselLite({
            vertical: true,
            hoverPause: true,
            visible: 4,
            auto: 6000,
            speed: 500,
            scroll: 4
        });
    };
```

Ideally I am looking to be able to add something like:

```
   function scrollwindow() {
        $("#tableapp").jCarouselLite({
            vertical: true,
            hoverPause: true,
            visible: 4,
            auto: 6000,
            speed: 500,
            scroll: 4,
            whenFinishedCyclingItems: updateConsoles()
        });
    };
```

I am pretty new to javascript and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#doc) has an `afterEnd` function.

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
function scrollwindow() {
        $("#tableapp").jCarouselLite({
            vertical: true,
            hoverPause: true,
            visible: 4,
            auto: 6000,
            speed: 500,
            scroll: 4,
            afterEnd: updateConsoles()
        });
    };
```

I'm not positive if you'd have to wrap that function inside another function or not, but just in case, the code would be:

```
afterEnd: function(){updateConsoles();}
```

Comment: That worked! For further knowledge, how did you find the afterEnd function? Was it somewhere in the jCarouselLite script? I'd like to see if I can find one for "beforeStart".  That way I can cycle all of the list items so they come back to zero THEN reload data.  As it is now, the data is reloading while I am staring at the bottom 4 items.

Comment: Found it in the documentation.  Just have to look harder!

 * option- beforeStart, afterEnd : function - callbacks
 * example
 * $(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
 *      btnNext: ".next",
 *      btnPrev: ".prev",
 *      beforeStart: function(a) {
 *          alert("Before animation starts:" + a);
 *      },
 *      afterEnd: function(a) {
 *          alert("After animation ends:" + a);
 *      }
 * });

Comment: There is a before start function. Just look at the [jCarouselLite docs](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#doc) to see the list of options. Glad that helped :)